# I can't make a message box

Tags: c#

I want my form to display an error message that pops up when the user doesn't enter a number or if the text box is blank. I have tried:

```
 //If nothing is inserted in text, error box.
        int value = 0;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtBegin.Text) || !int.TryParse(txtBegin.Text, out value)) // Test for null or empty string or string is not a number
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number!");
        else
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You entered: {0}!", value));
```

It is giving me an error:`'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsNullOrWhitespace'`

Comment: You don't want the `;` at the end of the `if`.

Comment: `if(textBegin = " ");` is not valid boolean expression. `if(textBegin == "")` is what you want.

Comment: Recommend: `if( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBegin) )`

Comment: Its a window or web application?

Comment: @AaronLS good catch. That is the preferred method.

Comment: @AaronLS It is giving me a lot of errors when doing that.

Comment: @GunnarBates probably because `txtBegin` isn't a string but a control.

Comment: Then it's probably not a string.  Maybe there is a txtBegin.Value or txtBegin.Text property on it.  We don't see what txtBegin is declared as so we can only guess its type.

Comment: That's using jeraldov's answer at the bottom? Try Phillip's, but use `txtBegin.Text` instead of just `txtBegin`, and `MessageBox.Show()` for the last line not `Message.Show()`.

Comment: @Rup It is giving me 1 error, 'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsNullOrWhitespace'.

Comment: @Rup Can you please help me with the error?

Comment: IsNullOrWhitespace is new in .NET 4 - are you using something older? You can use IsNullOrEmpty but that won't cover the whitespace-only-string case. However Phillip's other check, the number parse check, should catch strings that aren't numbers too so you should be fine without it. (Oops, didn't spot Lex Li had beaten me to this below. Did that solve your problem?)

Answer (score 2):

```
int value = 0;
if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtBegin) || !int.TryParse(txtBegin, out value) ) //Test for null or empty string or string is not a number
  MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number!");
else
  MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You entered: {0}!", value));
```

Comment: @PhiilipNgan It is giving me an error: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsNullOrWhitespace'

Comment: Any help? Still unanswered.

Comment: @GunnarBates, `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` is only available for .NET 4+. If your C# project is targeting .NET 2 or 3.*, you can only used `string.IsNullOrEmpty`. If you are a C# beginner, try to read beginners' book on C# and .NET first. Posting such questions on SO won't give enough help on learning the basics.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtBegin)){
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number!");
}
```

Comment: That debugs his code a little but actually his requirements are to show it if blank or not a number.

Comment: It is giving me an error operator '==' cannot be applied to operands. :(

Answer (score 1):

It is actually `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` - with capital `S`. Or try `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This one would do. Check if there is a value in the textbox and then remove the space, and check if the length is zero.

```
if (txtBox1.Text.Length>0 && txtBox1.Text.Trim().Length==0)
{
MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number!");
}
```

Comment: I didn't down-vote either but at first glance that'll match only non-empty strings of whitespace and not the empty string.